# Passport OAuth2 strategy / facebook strategy is loosing user

Tags: facebook, express, oauth-2.0, passport.js

I am trying to authorize a pre logged in user with a Facebook account. I want to store the auth token of Facebook to later post stuff using my CMS.

I am using Express/NodeJS and Passport JS.

My FacebookStrategy looks like this:

```js
module.exports = new FacebookStrategy(
  {
    clientID,
    clientSecret,
    callbackURL: `${config.apiUrl}/v1/auth/connect/facebook/callback`, 
    passReqToCallback: true
  },
  async function(req, token, tokenSecret, profile, done) {
    console.log("SESSION?", req.session)
    console.log("THIS SHOULD BE SET!", req.user) // But is not!

    // Stuff is done.

    done(null, token, {savedConnectionForLaterUse});
  }
```

I also have two routes:

```js
router.get('/connect/facebook',
  API_KEY_OR_JWT_AUTH_MIDDLEWARE,
  (req, res, next) => {
    // Save authInfo in session
    Object.assign(req.session, {account: req.authInfo.account._id, user: req.user._id})
    
    passport.authorize('facebookConnect', { 
      failureRedirect: `${frontUrl}/settings/connections`, 
      scope: facebookOAuthScopes, // This is an array of scopes I need 
    })(req, res, next)
  },
);

router.get('/connect/facebook/callback',
  passport.authorize('facebookConnect', {
    failureRedirect: `${apiUrl}/v1/auth/connect/facebook/failure`,
  }),
  (req, res) => {
    const { session: {connection} } = req;

    res.redirect(`${frontUrl}/settings/connections/edit/${connection}`);
  }
);
```

When I am running this on my local machine it works due to the fact that the session is there and in the session I can find my user for later use. As soon as I am deploying this on a server (with kubernetes) the session is gone.

The configuration of the express session looks like this:

```js
app.use(
    expressSession({
        secret: config.security.secret,
        resave: true,
        saveUninitialized: true,
        cookie: {
            sameSite: 'none', // This was something I tried.. didn't help thou
            secure: true,
        },
    })
)
```

Can anyone point me into the right direction? What am I doing wrong?

Thank you all for your help in advance. I am really at the end of my knowledge. The struggle is real! :D

Comment: How do you store sessions in the production? By default, express-session middleware keeps session in memory, which may work locally, but on cluster you can hit a different instance of your app, it can be restarted etc. Check the express-session documentation for more details (note the Warning): https://github.com/expressjs/session#sessionoptions

Comment: That was very smart. Thank you jnv, that was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The solution, to the problem, was using a MongoDB Session storage to save the session between of the OAuth Request. This ensures that the session is known to whatever instance the request from Facebook receives because it is not stored in memory but in a central database every instance of the cluster has access to.

Thank you jnv for pointing that out.